# ProcessBuilder redirecting output

Tags: java, process, processbuilder

I am trying to redirect output of a process started with the help of ProcessBuilder using following code

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/myScript >> /myLogFile 2>&1 <& - &");
Map<String, String> env = pb.environment();
env.clear();
env.put("var1", "val1");
env.put("var2", "val2");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
```

But it failed with exception

> Exception in thread "main"
>    java.io.IOException: Cannot run
>    program
>    "/myScript >>
>    /myLogFile
>    2>&1 <& - &": java.io.IOException:
>   error=2, No such file or directory    at
>   java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:460)

It works fine when I just pass "/myScript"

Script is perl, any suggestions/coments on why it is failing?

I tried passing all of them as seperate arguments like `new ProcessBuilder("/myScript",">>","/myLogFile")`, it executes but it does not redirect to log file and also it does not take envVars.

Comment: See also [How do I Pipe process output to a file on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17089875/how-do-i-pipe-process-output-to-a-file-on-windows-and-jdk-6u45)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65649701/839733

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shell redirection operators are unknown to [`ProcessBuilder`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). Put your command in a shell script and execute it, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1980671/executing-untokenized-command-line-from-java/1980921#1980921). Alternatively, use `bash -c`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740390/printing-my-macs-serial-number-in-java-using-unix-commands/5740673#5740673).

Comment: Yeah thanks, looks like Java 7 is going to have the capability of explicitly specifying the redirection.

Answer (score 1):

As you specified, from Java7 you can keep using ProcessBuilder with the only executable file as parameter and redirect/intercept its output stream, using `redirectInput()` `redirectOutput()` and `redirectError()` from `ProcessBuilder` class.