# How to show report from a JButton

Tags: java, swing, jasper-reports

I am developing a simple database application with *Java* as the front-end and *MySQL* as my back-end database. I am trying to use *iReport*. Now I have a *Java* form created using *Netbeans IDE*. I want to have a *JButton* in that form and when I press that button, I should get a report with some values displayed on it.

Kindly help me out in achieving that.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) I mean *besides* asking random strangers on the internet to do it for you.

Comment: Andrew::: Ya I have tried ... but id didnt work... that is why I am asking for help

Comment: *"Ya I have tried"*  The question was not *'have you tried anything?'* it was **'what have you tried?'**,  pay attention & explain in code. *"but id didnt work..."*  Gee, can you vague that up for me?   That is about as useful as a screen-door on a submarine.  What did you expect to happen?  What happened instead?  Voting to close as 'not a real question'.

Comment: @venkateshsridharan *iReport* is just an editor for designing report's templates. What is a reason to call it?

Answer (score 2):

Simply add an `ActionListener` to the `JButton`:

```
JButton btn=new JButton("Do something");

btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // do something for button 
        }
});
```

If you want Netbeans to do it for you:

- Drag a `JButton` from the *palette* to your container (Select Windows > Palette to open the Palette if you don't see it. You use the Palette to drag and drop UI components to the design area)
- Simply double click on the `JButton` in question in the designer view and it will auto create an `ActionListener` and override `actionPerformed`. and in the method it creates is here you would do the work. It should generate something like:

  ```
  private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
       //TODO: Add your handling code here:
  }
  ```

Comment: David :: I know how about actionlisteners... But I want to know what method to call for the ireport to be triggered.

Comment: @venkateshsridharan: you can run it as a command line using `ProcessBuilder`, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5986376/230513).