# Redirect output of echo to file through Java

Tags: java, process, processbuilder, io-redirection

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ProcessBuilder redirecting output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986324/processbuilder-redirecting-output)

The following code:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {"echo", "some text", ">", "test"});
```

keeps returning "`some text > test`".

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

this worked

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[] {"bash", "-c", "echo sometext > test"});
```

Comment: Accepted answer from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740390/printing-my-macs-serial-number-in-java-using-unix-commands/5740673#5740673) worked

Comment: Cool.  Glad you got it sorted, and thanks for reporting back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = 
new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c" ,"echo", "some text", ">", "test");
```

This is for **windows**

Actually 'Echo' is not a command its an internal command of the shell (cmd.exe) in windows and "bash" in **linux** or **unix**. So , for Unix/Linux

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = 
new ProcessBuilder("bash", "-c","echo \"some text\" >test");
```

Comment: Doesn't work, still returns everything after **echo**

Comment: Strange thing is that when i use same thing in Android it works fine, but in pure java on pc it wont redirect

Comment: link you added is for windows, i dont know if it makes any difference but im on linux

Comment: edited answer with **Reason** and *Solution* for *Windows* and *Unix*