# IntelliJ IDEA - Cannot resolve method

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

I am developing for Android with IntelliJ, using Java version 1.7. I haven't been having any problems of this nature until I do this:

```
    ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("echo", "hello world")
            .redirectErrorStream(true)
            .directory(dirFile)
            .redirectOutput(new File(""));
```

IntelliJ highlights "redirectOutput" in red and when I mouse over it, it says:

> Cannot resolve method 'redirectOutput(java.io.File)'

I have tried rebuilding, invalidating cache and restarting, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProcessBuilder doesn´t support `.redirectOutput`. 
Read more about it [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Try to use something like  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1980921/5603448).

Comment: Damn. I would have to write something that reads in input from the process and writes it to a file then?